# Why does 'mvn clean install' fail with multi-modules project whereas 'mvn test' works?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I've created a SpringBoot2.4.2/Maven/Java8 project like this :

- hr-sprg (parent project 1.0-SNAPSHOT)

  - hr-objects-sprg (module 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)
  - hr-cucumber-sprg (module 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT with dependency on hr-objects)

I've created a dummy object in `hr-objects` and test it both in `hr-objects` and in `hr-cucumber` (unit tests).

Import is OK, object is instanciated and tests pass.

When I want to clean install the parent project, I have this error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/citizenweb/games/hrsprg/hrobjectssprg/entities/Game at    com.citizenweb.games.hrsprg.hrcucumbersprg.HrCucumberSprgApplicationTests.createGame(HrCucumberSprgApplicationTests.java:17)
```

I've done many tries since a few days, always finishing with an error saying that the Game object isn't found.

But if I do a clean test or clean test test-compile, it works.

> I don't understand why "mvn test" is OK while "mvn install" fails.

I've passed a lot of time to resolve this problem, but I'm drying now.

Have you any suggestions ?

I can show u :

[Parent POM](https://pastebin.com/qGnykZ0r)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.citizenweb.games</groupId>
    <artifactId>hr-sprg</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>hr-sprg</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <modules>
        <module>../hr-objects-sprg</module>
        <module>../hr-cucumber-sprg</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

[hr-objects POM](https://pastebin.com/uSwaa30Q)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.citizenweb.games</groupId>
        <artifactId>hr-sprg</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../hr-sprg</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.citizenweb.games.hr-sprg</groupId>
    <artifactId>hr-objects-sprg</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>hr-objects-sprg</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

[hr-cucumber POM](https://pastebin.com/BePy4kE4)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.citizenweb.games</groupId>
        <artifactId>hr-sprg</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../hr-sprg</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.citizenweb.games.hr-sprg</groupId>
    <artifactId>hr-cucumber-sprg</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>hr-cucumber-sprg</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.citizenweb.games.hr-sprg</groupId>
            <artifactId>hr-objects-sprg</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

---

Following a response made to my question, I think these informations could be usefull :

**M2 folder content :**

[image: M2 content] :

**HR-OBJECTS JAR content :**

[image: HR-OBJECTS JAR content :]

Comment: Please put the poms into the question. We don't really want linked code on stackoverflow because it tends to be removed and the question loses its value to others that way.

Answer (score 0):

First you said:

> Import is OK, object is instanciated and tests pass.

Then:

> Now with IntelliJ, problem arise... (I've seen posts about similar
> problems with Idea)

You contradict to yourself. Your first statement means actually that IDEA works perfectly. The problem occurs not with IDEA, but with Maven. Please be more precise in what are you saying :)

> Have you any suggestions ?

1. Check if your directory structure corresponds to structure in pom.xml. According to your pom.xml files, all projects are in the same directory, module projects are *not nested* into the parent project "hr-prg". If actually the modules are subdirectories of "hr-prg", then adjust all pom.xml files accordingly.
2. I suppose that you use IDEA to compile your code and to run tests. That's why it works. IDEA compiles the needed code, sets class path accordingly and all needed classes will be found. But when you execute test with Maven, maven needs JAR for every dependency. I suppose you have built module "hr-objects-sprg" before there was class Game. After you created class Game, you have not rebuilt "hr-objects-sprg" with Maven.
   What can you do in such case? First "clean install" for "hr-objects-sprg". This will update JAR in your local Maven repository. Then run your tests.

Comment: As you can see, I've added pics showing folders structure. First one confirms that Maven Reactor has done the job in the right order : first the Parent was processed, then the HR-OBJECTS (because its JAR is needed by the following) and finally the HR-CUCUMBER which need the JAR of the preceeding.
The second one is the content of the HR-OBJECTS's JAR itself. We can see that there is an "Entities" package containing the "Game.class" file.
Its coordinates are the same IDEA is using when importing the "Game" class.
As you know, IDEA help us a lot when writing the POM by selecting the right path